Cannot disable CORS in Spring Cloud Gateway
IN the frontend React Web App.
import { useState } from "react"

export default function PrestadoresServico() {

    const [prestadoresServicos, setPrestadoresServicos] = useState([])





      fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/prestadores-servicos').then( (response) => {
            return response.json()
      }).then( (dadosRetornados) => {

          console.log(dadosRetornados)

      } )

    return (
    

    <div><h1>Listagem Prestadores de Serviço</h1> <a href="prestador-servico/novo" >Adicionar Prestador de Serviço +</a></div>


)
}

My gateway application.yml file
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    globalcors:
      corsConfigurations:
        '[/**]':
          allowedOrigins: "http://localhost"
          allowedHeaders: "*"
          allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
            - PUT

server:
  port: 8080

eureka:
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

The gateway routing
package br.com.syscomercial.gateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
        return builder.routes().route(r -> r.path("/api/prestadores-servicos/**").uri("lb://prestadorservico"))
                .route(r -> r.path("/api/avaliacoes-prestadores-servicos/**").uri("lb://avaliacaoprestadorservico")).build();
    }

}

Error on the browser console.

